# How can i create multiple tabs based on the dropdown selection using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am posting this question because I couldn't find a definite answer or method of doing so anywhere. What I want to do is, I have created a dropdown named as 'Number of Chasis'. Now according to the dropdown selected in this field (either '1' or '2')I want one tab 'UUT1' if the user selects '1' in the dropdown and I want two tabs 'UUT1' and 'UUT2' if the user selects '2' in the dropdown. And then on Clicking the UUT1 and UUT2 tabs if want to display the template which I have defined below. Attaching the html part here and also the screenshot of potentially what I am looking for.

```
            <fieldset id='extra'>
                <h6>Additional Details Required for Controller A</h6>
                <label for='Controller_ID1'>Controller_ID:</label>
                    <select name='Controller_ID1' required>
                    <option value=""> - Select the Controller ID - </option>
                    <option value='A'>A </select>
                <label for='iSCSI1'>iSCSI IPs:</label><input type='text' name='iSCSIip1' id="ip1" placeholder='Enter iSCSI ips'  disabled="disabled" />
                <label for='HBA_Ports_A'>HBA_Ports:</label><input type='text' id="hba" name='hba_ports1'  placeholder='Enter the HBA Ports' disabled="disabled" />
                <label for='MC_IP_A'>MC_IP:</label><input type='text' name='extra_ip1' placeholder='Enter the MC_IP' /> 
                <label for='MC_Netmask_A'>MC_Netmask:</label><input type='text' name='netmask_ip1' placeholder='Enter the MC_Netmask' /> 
                <label for='MC_Gateway_A'>MC_Gateway:</label><input type='text' name='gateway_ip1' placeholder='Enter the MC_Gateway' /> 
                <label for='MC_A'>MC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_mc1' placeholder='Enter the MC Port' onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)" /> 
                <label for='SC_A'>SC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_sc1' placeholder='Enter the SC Port' onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)" /> 
                <label for='FU_A'>FU:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_fu1' placeholder='Enter the FU Port' onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)"/> 
                <label for='EC_A'>EC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_ec1' placeholder='Enter the EC Port' onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)" /> 
<br>
<br>
                <h6>Additional Details Required for Controller B</h6>
                <label for='Controller_ID'>Controller_ID:</label>
                    <select name='Controller_ID' id="ctlid" required>
                    <option value=""> - Select the Controller ID - </option>
                    <option value='B'>B </select>
                <label for='iSCSI2'>iSCSI IPs:</label><input type='text' name='iSCSIip2' id="ip2" placeholder='Enter iSCSI ips' disabled="disabled" />
                <label for='HBA_Ports'>HBA_Ports:</label><input type='text' id="hba1" name='hba_ports' placeholder='Enter the HBA Ports' disabled="disabled" />
                <label for='MC_IP'>MC_IP:</label><input type='text' name='extra_ip' id='mcip' placeholder='Enter the MC_IP'  /> 
                <label for='MC_Netmask'>MC_Netmask:</label><input type='text' name='netmask_ip' id="netmaskip" placeholder='Enter the MC_Netmask' /> 
                <label for='MC_Gateway'>MC_Gateway:</label><input type='text' name='gateway_ip' id="gatewayip" placeholder='Enter the MC_Gateway'  /> 
                <label for='MC'>MC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_mc' placeholder='Enter the MC Port' id="rbodmc"onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)" /> 
                <label for='SC'>SC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_sc' placeholder='Enter the SC Port' id="rbodsc" onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)" /> 
                <label for='FU'>FU:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_fu' placeholder='Enter the FU Port' id="rbodfu" onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)" /> 
                <label for='EC'>EC:</label><input type='text' name='rbod_ec' placeholder='Enter the EC Port' id="rbodec" onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)" /> 

            </fieldset>
        </template> 
<fieldset>
                <label for='Chasis Input'><strong>Number of Chasis</strong></label>
                <select input type='text' name='chassis'   required >
                <option value=""> - Number of Controllers - </option>
                <option data-extra=true value='1'>1
                <option data-extra=true value='2'>2
                </select>
            </fieldset> 
            <fieldset>
                <label for='Number of Controllers'><strong>Number of Controllers</strong></label>
                <select input type='text' name='ctrls' onchange="EnableDisableDropDown(this);"  required >
                <option value=""> - Number of Controllers - </option>
                <option data-extra=true value='1'>1
                <option data-extra=true value='2'>2
                </select>
            </fieldset>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share a link with a reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below code. also please find fiddle link in comment. If you need more help please create fiddle of your example.

```
<h2>Tabs</h2>
<select id="tabsToDisplay">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select><br/><br/>

<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" id= "tab1btn" >tab1</button>
  <button class="tablinks" id= "tab2btn" >tab2</button>  
</div>

<div id="tab1" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tab1</h3>
  <p>You selected tab1</p>
</div>

<div id="tab2" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tab2</h3>
  <p>You selected tab2</p>
</div>
// A $( document ).ready() block.
$( document ).ready(function() {  
 function displaySelectedTabs(selectedNumber){
 switch(selectedNumber){
  case "1":
  $("#tab2btn").hide();
  $("#tab2").hide();      
  break;
  case "2":
  $("#tab2btn").show();
  break;  
 }
}
var selectedNumber = $("#tabsToDisplay").val();
displaySelectedTabs(selectedNumber);
 function tabClick(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
$("#tab1btn" ).click(function() {
  tabClick(event, 'tab1');
});
$("#tab2btn" ).click(function() {
  tabClick(event, 'tab2');
});
$( "#tabsToDisplay" ).change(function() {
  var selectedNumber = $("#tabsToDisplay").val();
displaySelectedTabs(selectedNumber);
});    
});
```

Comment: fiddle link for above answer. https://jsfiddle.net/shivpatne/hd4qLxky/